# Stuck with java8 lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have `Map<Integer,Doctor> docLib=new HashMap<>();` to save class of `Doctor`.

`Class Doctor` has `methods:getSpecialization()` return a `String`,
`getPatients(`) to return a collection of class `Person`.

In the main method, I type:

```
public Map<String,Set<Person>> getPatientsPerSpecialization(){
    Map<String,Set<Person>> res=this.docLib.entrySet().stream().
                         map(d->d.getValue()).
                         collect(groupingBy(d->d.getSpecialization(),
                                            d.getPatients()) //error
                                 );
   return res;
}
```

As you can see, I have problem with `groupingBy`,I try to send the same value d to the method, but it's wrong.
How to solve this?

Comment: It seems like you got some good answers to this question, but in the future, please include the exact error message you receive, and descriptions of any other behavior that differs from your expected behavior. Saying "it's wrong" doesn't say much about your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a second Collector for that [mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) :

```
public Map<String,Set<Person>> getPatientsPerSpecialization(){
    return this.docLib
               .values()
               .stream()
               .collect(Colectors.groupingBy(Doctor::getSpecialization,
                                             Collectors.mapping(Doctor::getPatients,toSet()))
                       );
}
```

EDIT:

I think my original answer may be wrong (it's hard to say without being able to test it). Since `Doctor::getPatients` returns a Collection, I think my code may return a `Map<String,Set<Collection<Person>>>` instead of the desired `Map<String,Set<Person>>`.

The easiest way to overcome that is to iterate over that `Map` again to produce the desired `Map` :

```
public Map<String,Set<Person>> getPatientsPerSpecialization(){
    return this.docLib
               .values()
               .stream()
               .collect(Colectors.groupingBy(Doctor::getSpecialization,
                                             Collectors.mapping(Doctor::getPatients,toSet()))
                       )
               .entrySet()
               .stream()
               .collect (Collectors.toMap (e -> e.getKey(),
                                           e -> e.getValue().stream().flatMap(c -> c.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet()))
                        );
}
```

Perhaps there's a way to get the same result with a single Stream pipeline, but I can't see it right now.

Comment: Instead of `docLib.entrySet().stream().map(d->d.getValue())` you can write `docLib.values().stream()`.

Comment: [Wait for Java 9 ;-)](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)

Comment: @Holger cool :). I was wondering if I was missing some way of doing this flat mapping in Java 8. I guess I wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `groupingBy`, you could use `toMap`:

```
public Map<String, Set<Person>> getPatientsPerSpecialization() {
    return docLib.values()
                 .stream()
                 .collect(toMap(Doctor::getSpecialization,
                                d -> new HashSet<>(d.getPatients()),
                                (p1, p2) -> Stream.concat(p1.stream(), p2.stream()).collect(toSet())));
}
```

What it does is that it groups the doctors per specialization and map each one to a set of the patients it has (so a `Map<String, Set<Person>>`).

If, when collecting the data from the pipeline, you encounter a doctor with a specialization that is already stored as a key in the map, you use the merge function to produce a new set of values with both sets (the set that is already stored as a value for the key, and the set that you want to associate with the key).